# Assigning dynamic value to attribute in xslt file

Tags: xslt, soa, jdeveloper, bpel

We are working on integrating one of the server where target server required input payload in below format. In this we have to pass couple of argument and there value where one of them is dynamic.
As highlighted in below payload, for attribute storeID, we need to pass a value which should be coming from a transformation. I dont see an option through which I can do the transformation in SOA 11g

note :- I have a variable created in BPEL and same variable needs to be passed here.

Could someone pls help on this.

```
<modifyRequest dn="storeID=123456780,ou=store,o=xxxx.com">
 <modification name="TelephoneNo" operation="replace">
      <value>1231231230</value>
 </modification>
```

This is how my xslt file look like :-

```
<ns6:modifyRequest>
    <xsl:attribute name="dn">
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">storeID=123456780,ou=sites,o=xxxx.com</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <ns6:modification>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">TelephoneNo</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="operation">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">replace</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <ns6:value>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">1212121212</xsl:text>
      </ns6:value>
     </ns6:modification>
  </ns6:modifyRequest>
```

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but I strongly recommend NOT using disable-output-escaping unless you seriously have no choice. Aside from not being supported in every XSLT processor, it's completely unnecessary in this case, and may even lead to errors in your generated XML, depending on the text you're outputting.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using [`xsl:text`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Text) to output fixed (constant) text, you can use [`xsl:value-of`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#value-of) to output text resulting from an evaluation of an [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) expression.

You can simply interleave `xsl:text` and `xsl:value-of`. Assuming for example that you have a variable named `storeID`:

```
<xsl:text>storeID=</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$storeID"/>
<xsl:text>,ou=sites,o=xxxx.com</xsl:text>
```

Or, alternatively, have a look at the [`concat`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-concat) XPath function for concatenating strings.

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('storeID=', $storeID, ',ou=sites,o=xxxx.com')"/>
```